# Functional maximization problem - Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, optimization

I am triying to solve the following functional maximization problem:

$\max_{x(\theta)} \int_0^{x(\theta)]+c} [\theta-x(\theta)]x(\theta)d\theta +  \int_{x(\theta)]+c}^1 \big[\frac{\theta-x(\theta)+c}{2} \big]x(\theta)d\theta$

subject to:

$\int_0^1 x(\theta) d\theta=0$

I think that I cannot use pointwise maximzation, since the boundaries of the integral are not a function of $x(\theta)$. How do I solve this problem then?

One idea (that is probably wrong) is to realize that the problem above is equal to

$\max_{x(\theta)} \int_0^{1} \min \big\{\theta-x(\theta), \frac{\theta-x(\theta)+c}{2}\big\} x(\theta)d\theta$

subject to:

$\int_0^1 x(\theta) d\theta=0$

Then, I can look for the optimal solution by solving the following two lagrangians:

$\max_{x(\theta)} \int_0^{1} \big\{\theta-x(\theta)\big\} x(\theta)d\theta + \lambda \int_0^1 x(\theta) d\theta$

and:

$\max_{x(\theta)} \int_0^{1} \frac{\theta-x(\theta)+c}{2} x(\theta)d\theta +  \lambda \int_0^1 x(\theta) d\theta$

It turns put that the solution to the two problems is the same, and it is given by $x(\theta) = \frac{\theta}{2}-\frac{1}{4}$

Does this make any sense? What do you think?

Comment: What are the variables here? Are you maximising over a single value $x(\theta)$ or  over a collection if functions $x$? If the latter, what is the space of functions under consideration?

Comment: I am looking for x as a function of $\theta$. For instance, if the problem is $\max_{x(\theta)} \int_0^{1} \big\{\theta-x(\theta)\big\} x(\theta)d\theta + \lambda \int_0^1 x(\theta) d\theta$ subject to $\int_0^1 x(\theta) d\theta$, I would do pointwise maximization. The FOC is $\theta-2x(\theta)+\lambda=0$ for all $\theta$, which yields the solution $x(\theta)=\frac{2\theta-1}{4}$ for all $\theta$. My problem now is that the boundaries of the integral depend on $x(\theta)$.